# How to set up Dynamic DNS to view Pi camera stream remotely

Tags: dns, camera, streaming, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have followed the main tutorials to set up a motion activated raspi camera. I can get it to stream locally. On my pi's IPadress on port 8080 like so, IPADDRESS:8080

It only works on my local network. I also tried setting up a dynamic dns service, which I can now also view my feed at username.dnsdynamic.com:8080, but it STILL does not work outside my local network.

I have searched through tons of tutorials but there are zoo many and none of them have worked for me so far.

I am utterly confused with networking stuff. I am pretty tech savvy, but I am at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I really want to be able to post a complete guide on how to do the whole setup as I have had to peicemeal different guides/tutorials together in order for me to get it up and running.

Comment: Are you connecting to the internet via a router so that your local devices gets internal ip addresses (e.g. 192.168.*.*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are connecting the pi to a router you will have configure port forwarding on your router so that requests from outside your local network gets forwarded to the pi.

You will at least need to forward the HTTP traffic from some port on your routers internet facing interface to the correct port (8080) and ip address for your pi. If the camera stream uses another port you will have set up port forwarding for that port as well.

Comment: Thank you. I have forwarded 8080 to my pi's ip address already, still can't connect from the outside.

Comment: Ok. Can you check from outside that port 8080 is open on your router? That gives some indication to whether the port forwarding is active or not. If it is, than check if the request are getting forwarded to the pi by looking at the webserver access log at the pi.

Comment: I just checked on two services online and it says they are closed. Even though on my router i set up port 8080 and pointed it to my Pi's ip address.

Comment: Strange... Maybe your ISP is blocking that port from the outside. Perhaps other ports are available. Try to open port 80 from the outside and forward the requests to the internal 8080 port and see if that works.